# youtube jQuery Player works for the favorites playlist but not for other playlists

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api

for these examples I am using

youtube.com/user/Google/videos?view=1

a jQuery YouTube player (Simone Gianni) works perfectly if one is accessing the "favorites" playlist

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Google/favorites?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=?',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hL8zK/3/

but when accessing custom playlists the thumbnails populate but the click function does not generate the unique video id - I am guessing that there are some additional elements when calling custom playlists preventing the video id from being generated.

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/playlists/5400F84F30D9651E?&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=?',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hL8zK/5/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. After some research, I found that video ID for playlists is a little different. Try this for var video id:

```
this.media$group.yt$videoid.$t
```

and the json URL like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/5400F84F30D9651E?v=2&alt=json&callback=?
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL8zK/15/)